# CodeForces: Creating the Contest

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I wrote a solution to [this question](http://codeforces.com/contest/1029/problem/B). The task is to take an input of *n* increasing positive integers (1 ≤  *n* ≤ 2∙10<sup>5</sup>), each entry as large as 10<sup>9</sup>, and find the length of the longest subsequence where each element is no more than double the previous element.

#### Example input

```
10
1 2 5 6 7 10 21 23 24 49
```

#### Example output

```
4
```

… because the longest subsequence is [5, 6, 7, 10].

---

My solution works for small numbers, but exceeds the time limit for big inputs.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{    

 int n,a,c=1,max_count=1;
 cin>>n;
 vector<int>v;
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     cin>>a;
    v.push_back(a);
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int l=i+1;
    while((l<n)&&(v[l]<=2*v[i]))
    {
        c++;
        l++;
        max_count=max(max_count,c);
    }

    c=1;
}
cout<<""<<max_count;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to store the entries in a vector. There is also no need for a nested loop.  This solution will run in O(*n*) time and O(1) space.

Technically, `int` is only guaranteed to hold up to 16 bits. Use `long` to ensure that you can accommodate the limits.

Also, please avoid `using namespace std;`. You can drop the useless `cout<<""`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long n, a, seq_len = 0, longest = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (long prev_a = 0; n--; prev_a = a) {
        std::cin >> a;
        if (a <= 2 * prev_a) {
            seq_len++;
        } else {
            seq_len = 1;
        }
        longest = std::max(longest, seq_len);
    }
    std::cout << longest << '\n';
}
```

Comment: A minor optimization, if you assign `longest` inside the `else` block before you re-assign `seq_len`, you only call `max` when a sequence ends, instead of at each iteration.